# is Service really private

Tags: android

I have a service that read users data , like contact , musics , images , files , and .... '
I want to know is service really private to my app , so only my app can read information not other apps read from my service , I have a service not Intent Service;

thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you haven't defined any interface to offer binding of your service to external applications, then *yes*, your service is only serving the app it is defined in.

Comment: If you haven't defined any [AIDL](http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/tools/aidl.html#ImplementTheInterface) for your service then **bind** is serving locally only